# How to handle DataReceived

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling

Please see my code below, that I am trying to return back to method that I registered the port's DataReceived event. Basically, If I recieve data from port before read time out. I will return back where I registered DataReceived event and degister and continue process. I am trying to do it with while loop. But not sure if it is accurate, and it is the way that has to be done
or if there is any other way to do this.

```
public class CommClass{
private static byte[] portReturn = null;

private void setUpDevice()
{
    byte[] command = { 0x11,0X51 };
    try
    {
        port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPortDataReceived);
        port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);
        while (portReturn == null) { } //Not sure if this will work. If I receive data before times out I do not want to wait in the loop.
        port.DataReceived -= serialPortDataReceived;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //to do
    }
}


private void serialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    var servicePort = (SerialPort)sender;
    portReturn = servicePort.ReadByte();
    return;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You code will technically work; however, your while loop will max out your CPU while you're waiting for data to come in, which is not what you want.  I recommend using a `ManualResetEvent` here to let you wait to receive data in a CPU friendly way.  You can read more about them [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
public class CommClass
{
    private static byte[] portReturn = null;

    // ManualResetEvents are great for signaling events across threads
    private static ManualResetEvent dataReceivedEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    private void setUpDevice()
    {
        byte[] command = { 0x11,0X51 };
        try
        {
            port.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(serialPortDataReceived);
            port.Write(command, 0, command.Length);

            // Wait for the event to be set without spinning in a loop.
            // Can also specify a timeout period to wait in case the data never comes.
            dataReceivedEvent.WaitOne();

            // Reset the event so that you can use it again later if necessary
            dataReceivedEvent.Reset();

            port.DataReceived -= serialPortDataReceived;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            //to do
        }
    }


    private void serialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var servicePort = (SerialPort)sender;
        portReturn = servicePort.ReadByte();

        // Set the event to let the main thread know you have received data
        dataReceivedEvent.Set();
    }
}
```